# Programmaticaly calling "Find Available Times" while scheduleing the service activity in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am new to MS CRM 2011. I want to call "Find Available Times" function problematically to know the nearest availability of resources,facilities and sites. The similar functionality provided by on schedule activity page. But i want to call this function from code. can you guys point me in right direction for solving my purpose. Does CRM sdk provides this kind of functions?

Ok, i googled about this, and it seems that SearchRequest of ServiceAppointment Entity will work for me according to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328326.aspx ), but in silverlight application it is not working coz to work with the example i am supposed to add "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll", but the silverlight application does not allow me to do so,
Any ideas freinds!!

Answer (score 0):

Any one who is searching the answer of the above question can find it at
[SearchRequest and SearchReponse Classes are not present for silverlight application in CRM 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934938/searchrequest-and-searchreponse-classes-are-not-present-for-silverlight-applicat)

Hope this helps to people like me.