# SearchRequest and SearchReponse Classes are not present for silverlight application in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i want to search all the available time slots for given resources in CRM 2011. Now CRM 2011 sdk provices a sammple for that in console application which is working fine but i want to do the same thing in silverlight applciation. In my silverlight application i am unable to find the SearchRequest and SearchReponse Classes.

Can any one help me how to do this in silverlight applciation?

Answer (score 0):

First prepare the AppointmentRequest object

```
     private void checkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            AppointmentRequest appReq = new AppointmentRequest
            {
                Objectives = new ObservableCollection<ObjectiveRelation>(),
                RequiredResources = new ObservableCollection<RequiredResource>(),
                AppointmentsToIgnore = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentsToIgnore>(),
                Constraints = new ObservableCollection<ConstraintRelation>(),
                Sites = new ObservableCollection<Guid>(),
        Duration = 60,
        Direction = SearchDirection.Forward,
        NumberOfResults = 5,
        ServiceId = new Guid("DD535FD0-F84B-E111-8F2F-00505688095F"),
        SearchWindowStart = DateTime.UtcNow,
        SearchWindowEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7.0),
        AnchorOffset = 300
    };

    OrganizationRequest req = new OrganizationRequest() { RequestName = "Search" };

    req["AppointmentRequest"] = appReq;

    IOrganizationService service = SilverlightUtility.GetSoapService();

    service.BeginExecute(req, new AsyncCallback(GetAppReqResult), service);
}

Following is the Asynchromus callback function

private void GetAppReqResult(IAsyncResult res)
{
   try
   {
     OrganizationResponse resp = 
                          ((IOrganizationService)res.AsyncState).EndExecute(res);

     SearchResults results = (SearchResults)resp["SearchResults"];

     this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ProcessAppointments(results));        

   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred");
   }
}
```

results object will contains the all possible time slots for an appointment request object passed.
Hope this help to the people like me